# How to Select by month and year in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, winrt-xaml, sqlite-net

In my SQlite table, it has DateTime field example : `order_date`

How to perform these tasks:

1. Retrieve records by Month like Jan, Feb, Mar and so on in Year 2013.
2. Retrieve records by Begin date and End Date with criteria like above(1)

Thanks

```
How to convert `DateTime` for format requires by SQLite for (1) and (2) 

    DateTime  Dt = new DateTime.Today();
    Month-year ?  Year?


    Records = await db.QueryAsync("Select * From Purchase where order_date=" + "Month-Year");

In SQLite , which operator is correct : `=` or `==`? 

----- Update:

using SQlite:strftime

SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE strftime('%Y', Order_Date) = '2013' AND strftime('%m', Order_Date) = '2';

1) Is there a function to get month as number from DateTime?
```

Comment: What is the format of the values in the `order_date` column?

Comment: This Order_date is take the value from DateTime when record is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [sqlite-net](/questions/tagged/sqlite-net).

As such you may use parameters in your query:

```
//Returning all records from February 2013
Records = await db.QueryAsync<Purchase>("Select * From Purchase where order_date >= ? and order_date < ?", new DateTime(2013, 2, 1), new DateTime(2013, 3, 1));
```

Comment: Your solution show a date range with format yyyy-mm-dd. I want to filter by yyyy-mm ( ie 2013-feb or 2013-february ?)

Comment: `2013-feb` is comprised of all dates from `2013-02-01` to (but not including) `2013-03-01`... What's the deal???

Comment: If you are sure that DateTime are written in database as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, you may use matching `LIKE '2013-02-%'`, but my answer is safer as [tag:sqlite-net] is handling DateTime.

Comment: What I mean is that I allow user to filter records. Examples : 2012-Feb and 2013-Feb, this way to avoid filter just by Feb. The DateTime is base on .Net and I insert it directly.  Order_Date = DateTime.Today. Is this a problem?

Comment: No, this is not a problem. [tag:sqlite-net] handles it (see [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)). You just should always use `DateTime` to ensure [tag:sqlite-net] always handle it in same way. "I allow user to filter records" - right, but users do it in your application, not in database directly!!! Your application must do anything beyond just connecting to database!!!

Comment: Just update the functions from SQLite. strftime(). Can Sqlite compare by month instead of Number-month : strftime('%m', Order_Date) = '2';

Comment: This is only a work around. E.g. it won't work with group by ...